# Filling Google Maps polygon from array of LatLng points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I have an array of coordinates in LatLng format. I would like to construct a polygon using those coordinates. I know I can hardcode a polygon with individual coordinates like this:

```
var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: A, lng: A},
    {lat: B, lng: B},
    {lat: C, lng: C}]
```

Is it possible to place the LatLng data points from my array into triangleCoords and create the polygon that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I had misunderstood your question.

**Q:**
Is it possible to place the LatLng data points from my array into triangleCoords and create the polygon that way?

**A:**

Short answer: No. Unfortunately there is no smartness in the `google.maps.Polygon` code which would magically try to figure out the `lat` and `lng` coordinates of the specified `google.maps.LatLng` objects for you.

You will need to use the `lat()` and `lng()` APIs to return the raw coordinate values from the `google.maps.LatLng` object and plug that into your array. No shortcut.

**Example:**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
{
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.7964, 79.8456),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
});

var coordinateA = new google.maps.LatLng(18.979026,72.949219);
var coordinateB = new google.maps.LatLng(28.613459,77.255859);
var coordinateC = new google.maps.LatLng(22.512557,88.417969);
var coordinateD = new google.maps.LatLng(12.940322,77.607422);

var coords =
    [
        {lat: coordinateA.lat(), lng: coordinateA.lng() },
        {lat: coordinateB.lat(), lng: coordinateB.lng() },
        {lat: coordinateC.lat(), lng: coordinateC.lng() },
        {lat: coordinateD.lat(), lng: coordinateD.lng() }
    ];

metros = new google.maps.Polygon(
    {
        paths: coords,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#0000FF",
        fillOpacity: 0.26
    });
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/3srggbmu/) for a working JSFiddle example.
http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/3srggbmu/

Answer (score 0):

Here same way am trying polygon google route map dynamically from mysql, it work only on marker, but its not working in polygon ,

here is the code

```php
function initMap() 
{

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
          zoom: 5,
          center: { lat: 13.36, lng: 77.03 },

      });

      var planCoordinates = new Array();
      // var locations = [
      //      {lat: 13.367797388285002, lng:77.03707749682616},
      //       {lat:13.341074247677549, lng:77.0394807561035},
      //       {lat:13.379153826558369, lng: 77.08685929614256},
      //       {lat: 13.367797388285002, lng:77.03707749682616},  
      // ];

    <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
     foreach($result as $key => $row) 
      {
       
  ?>
   
  var locations = [{lat: <?php echo $row['lat']; ?>,lng: <?php echo $row['lng']; ?>}];


      for (let i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

          let obj = locations[i];
          planCoordinates[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng);
          var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(obj.lat, obj.lng);

          poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            path: planCoordinates,
            geodesic: true,
            strokeColor: 'hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3)',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 3,
            fillColor: 'hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3)',
            fillOpacity: 1.35
          });
          poly.setMap(map);

          var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString.this });

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              title: "Jumbookart",
              zIndex: 999,
          });

          marker.setMap(map);

          let ikonica = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              title: "Markeri",
              icon: {
                  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                  scale: 7
              }

          });
          ikonica.setMap(map);

      }
<?php } } ?>
      var arrayOfFlightPlans = [locations];

  //Loops through all polyline paths and draws each on the map.
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfFlightPlans.length; i++) {
       flightPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
      path: arrayOfFlightPlans[i],
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: 'hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3)',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: 'hsla(290,60%,70%,0.3)',
        fillOpacity: 1.35
      });
      flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
  }
```